# Erro PHP - Não cadastra no banco de dados

Tags: php

O PHP retorna 4 erros ao eu tentar cadastrar um usuário no banco de dados, os erros são

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(fotos/2f66a74ededbbd39c3651c02e62998af.jpg): failed >to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP->Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 63
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phpD504.tmp' to 'fotos/2f66a74ededbbd39c3651c02e62998af.jpg' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 63
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 66
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 67

PHP:

```
// Recupera os dados dos campos
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$foto = $_FILES['foto'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$turmaid = $_POST['idturma'];
$rm = $_POST['rm'];
// Se a foto estiver sido selecionada
if (!empty($foto["name"])) {

    // Largura máxima em pixels
    $largura = 1000;
    // Altura máxima em pixels
    $altura = 1000;
    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
    $tamanho = 100000;

    $error = array();

    // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
    if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){
       $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
    } 

    // Pega as dimensões da imagem
    $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);

    // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
    if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
        $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
    if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
        $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
    if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
        $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
    }

    // Se não houver nenhum erro
    if (count($error) == 0) {

        // Pega extensão da imagem
        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

        // Gera um nome único para a imagem
        $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

        // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
        $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

        // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
        move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

        // Insere os dados no banco
        $insert = "INSERT INTO aluno (RM, Turma_ID, Foto, Nome, Email, Senha ) VALUES ('$rm','$turmaid','$foto','$nome','$email','$senha'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
        // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
        if ($sql){
            echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
        }
    }

    // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as
    if (count($error) != 0) {
        foreach ($error as $erro) {
            echo $erro . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="RM" type="number" tabindex="1" name="rm" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" name="email" required>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Nome" name="nome" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" tabindex="5" required>
</fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <input type="number" name="idturma" placeholder="ID Turma" tabindex="6" required>
</fieldset><br>
 <fieldset>
<input type="file" name="foto" placeholder="Foto"/ tabindex="7"><br>
</fieldset>
<br><fieldset>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Enviar</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha na parte

"... VALUES ('$rm','$turmaid','$foto','$nome','$email','$senha'";

Faltou fechar o parenteses:

"... VALUES ('$rm','$turmaid','$foto','$nome','$email','$senha'**)**";

Comment: Pois é amigo, eu percebi isso a pouco tempo atrás, entretanto os erros:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(fotos/7fd269490b7082594f1525d01dfff5b3.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 61

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phpDAF4.tmp' to 'fotos/7fd269490b7082594f1525d01dfff5b3.jpg' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\inseriraluno.php on line 61 
Persistem...